# Xamarin build failed with R8 error can't compily SpassFingerprint.class

Tags: .net, xamarin

I need to build an old Xamarin project, but i'm even used Xamarin.
While trying make an apk by archiving the project i'm getting an error:

`Error in obj\Debug\90\lp\7\jl\__reference__pass-v1.2.0.jar:com/samsung/android/sdk/pass/SpassFingerprint.class: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Index 4 out of bounds for length 4 Compilation failed with an internal error. java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: obj\Debug\90\lp\7\jl\__reference__pass-v1.2.0.jar com/samsung/android/sdk/pass/SpassFingerprint.class`

And can't google anything meaningful for this exception.
The project is on .net 5 and i'm using Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Did you try to rebuild your project?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT yes, no effort. I have installed VSS 2019 and error has gone. But i don't think it the correct way to solve the problem

Comment: That is the Xamarin project compatibility problem. It is recommended to use the .net 6 on the Visual Studio 2022 and Starting with the June 2022 servicing update for Visual Studio 2019 16.11 and Visual Studio 2019 16.9, the .NET 5.0 component in Visual Studio will be changed to out of support and optional. So that is why Xamarin build failed with R8 error.